# .net 4 multi-threading network connections limitation

Tags: .net, c#-4.0

i wonder why is that .net framework 4 System.Thread implementation only allows 2 TCP connection to be establish even I had initiated 10 threads to connect and fetch data?

i tried it on duo core and 4 core machines and both resulted the same as i uses netstat to read the connections.

Comment: Uhm, I think you should clarify your statement with some reproducible code.

Comment: There are no such limits, the problem is your code and not .NET framework. Rephrase your question and include the code that is not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has nothing to do with `Thread`, you would get the same behavior when using one thread and asynchronous operations.

There is a limit of 2 connections *per remote host* by default. This value can be changed by changing [`ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.servicepointmanager.defaultconnectionlimit.aspx). There is no limit for connections to different hosts by default, which can be changed by setting [`ServicePointManager.MaxServicePoints`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.servicepointmanager.maxservicepoints.aspx).

Comment: Is this for HTTP or TCP as well?

Comment: It seems `ServicePointManager` is used only when accessing a resource through a URI. So, it is used for HTTP or FTP, but not when using TCP directly.